# codeigniter : Ajax success function returning [object Object]

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I need to display results which are return from the my controller in my view

here is the my ajax,

```
$(function () {
    $(".branch").click(function () {
        var branch_id = $(this).attr("alt");
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo site_url('ajax_controller / getBranchDetails '); ?>',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                branch_id: branch_id
            },
            success: function (result) {
                //fetch result.data
                alert(result.data);
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Learn to `console.log()`

Comment: is it a question !? ~

Answer (score 0):

hi you just need to show your ajex returned data on browser console.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo site_url('ajax_controller / getBranchDetails '); ?>',
    data: {
                branch_id: branch_id
            },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){ console.log('result.data); }
});
```

and if u dont know where is your brwser console just right click and select inspect Element.

Comment: how can i get return value as php variable?, not in console.log. how can i display in html table if it is in console.log?

Comment: use selecter and add value to that e.g create one div with id 'mydata' and assign value to it. $("#mydata").html(result.data);